# How to make mobile Safari show a background gif properly

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, gif

I am trying to add a loading spinner to a web application where I have been provided with an animated gif that should be used as the icon. Right now I'm doing this with a div that is initially hidden via CSS and then is shown when I want to indicate loading. I'm using the following CSS on this div so that when its shown the loading gif appears in the center of the screen

```
    #loader {
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 10000;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 5px solid #3AACE2;
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
        background: url(/content/images/loader.gif);
        background-size: 128px 128px;
    }
```

This is working well on desktop and on android devices but in mobile Safari (on both an iPad and iPhone) the gif does not show. When the div is shown all that is visible is the border. I believe it has something to do with the fact that the div is hidden at first so the browser does not download the image. So I am not sure if there is a way to make it download the image or if perhaps there is a better way to do a loading spinner like this altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test in safari. i added -webkit for safari

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: -76px 0 0 -76px; 
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 16px solid #fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;

}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="loader"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/programming.gif" alt="Computer man" style="width:48px;height:48px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does appear to work in mobile Safari but if I understand correctly would the idea be that I would use an image in the center rather than an animated gif? The reason I was provided with a gif was because my client requested a specific animation using their logo and the gif itself is animated. So this may not serve my purposes exactly though it could work well as a backup plan.

Comment: please add your gif and see if it animates. if i understand correctly you do not need the spinning effect? Take animation spin down to 0s and test.

Comment: The css you added is basically just adding animation from what I can understand. Is that right? In my case the gif itself is already animated but the issue is that safari just won't show it. I don't need to spin the gif itself around I just need it to show up. The gif in your snippet does show up for me on ios safari but when I use your code in my application I still just have the issue of the gif not showing up at all.

Comment: Take the animation spin down to 0s and add your gif where mine is and test if it works, if your gif don't show then look at the root/link of the gif. If your gif work in my code then we need to find harmony within each others code and make our code flow together.

Comment: So it hasn't really fixed my initial problem but I was able to take your animation css to do a static image with a rotating border around it. That seems to show up well on mobile safari. Thanks for taking the time to help out!